# Wordpress live composer custom post taxonomy template

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm trying to create a [live composer](https://livecomposerplugin.com/) template for my custom post "products". For custom posts I use plugin Toolset types.

Live composer by default bring you some custom posts like gallery, partners etc but its not that I need. I need some structure similar to standard posts (and live composer way of show them) with custom field for images.

I found in [docs](https://livecomposer.help/article/133-add-post-templates-support-to-a-cpt) how to add my custom post to live composers templates. But there something is wrong. I create 2 templates - for archives and for single product. I have taxonomy "product category", my products are related to categories. If I create only template for archives - single products page grabs this template too. And if I create both templates - single is normal but archives grabs template of single.

I clicked all those options, buttons etc - nothing helps. Looks like i need some advanced modifications of functions.php or something like that. Whole live composer docs contains only one link about this CPT so i have not found nothing.

in functions.php I have tried :

```
function lc_add_products_support($cpt) {
    $cpt['product'] = 'Product';
    return $cpt;
} add_filter('dslc_post_templates_post_types', 'lc_add_products_support');

function lc_make_products_editable($cpt) {
    $cpt['product'] = 'Product';
    return $cpt;
}
add_filter('dslc_enabled_cpt', 'lc_make_products_editable');
```

It brings "products" to the templates list of posts to choose.
Second function I found on gitHub, seems it does nothing.

Maybe there is another way. I just need to view catalog of products sorted by categories.

Comment: Just do not use such constructors if you need some programmatic flexibility.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just do not use Live composer if you need more flexibility that it provides by default. There is another plugins witch are much more useful to work with. For example Site origin pagebuilder provides wider list of opportunities. If you you can work with markup you probably should try Advanced Custom Fields which provides very useful administration for your content.